# error running 'app' no target device found en android studio 3.5

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Amigos he instalado la ultima versión del IDE y genymotion para hacer pruebas, la cuestion es que al tratar de ejecutar mi app, no reconoce el emulador de genymotion ni el telefono fisico, ya instale el plugin de genymotion pero aun asi sigue sin detectar, al intentar ejecutar me aparece este mensaje `error running 'app' no target device found` alguien podria ayudarme en esto.

Comment: Con el teléfono físico es comprobado que este en modo debug y permita instalar apps por USB?

Comment: has intentado matar el proceso adb y volverlo a levantar? en ocasiones no reconoce el dispositivo ya sea virtual o físico hasta que reinicias el adb

Comment: Si ya pude solucionar reiniciando el servicio de adb

Comment: tengo el mismo problema. como puedo reiniciar el servicio de adb gracias

Comment: @JhonnyLuis ya solucionaste entonces  el problema planteado ennla pregunta.

Comment: si, efectivamente logre solucionarlo reiniciando el servicio de abd de la siguiente forma: ´´´adb nodaemon server´´´ luego se agrega los siguientes comando para listar que ip estan ocupadas y matar esos procesos ´´´netstat -ano | findstr 5037´´´  luego pueden matar el servicio y volver a activar asi: ´´´adb kill-server´´´ lo matamos, ahora lo montamos otra vez ´´´adb start-server´´´ y luego ejecutamos este comando para saber si todo esta bien ´´´adb devices´´´